# Accessing an element inside and outside of $( document ).ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to access an element, both inside and outside of the `$( document ).ready()` scope.

Assume the following code:

```
var text__holder = $('#text__holder');

$(function() {
    text__holder.text('Inside DOM ready');
    /*
      SOME MORE ACTION WITH ELEMENT
    */
});

var writeSomeTxt = function () {
    text__holder.text('Outside DOM ready');
};

writeSomeTxt();
```

In this case I can't access the element inside the function. The JS is also in external `.js` file which is included in `<head>` part of the page and I cant replace it elsewhere.

My current "workaround" for this is:

```
var text__holder = $('#text__holder');

$(function() {
    text__holder.text('Inside DOM ready');
    /*
      SOME MORE ACTION WITH ELEMENT
    */
});

var writeSomeTxt = function () {
 $(function() {
    text__holder.text('Outside DOM ready');
 });
};

writeSomeTxt();
```

Comment: Ok.  And what's your question?

Comment: If you place this code just before the `</body>` tag it should work. If you put it in the `<head>` then the `#text__holder` element will not yet exist in the DOM at the point you try and select it.

Comment: You do realize that it's on `document` ready for a reason? If there's no DOM, how will an element that doesn't exist have text?

Comment: @charlietfl it does work with the caveat I mentioned in my previous comment (although I admit it's just all over the place logically and needs improving). See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o1wgehzu/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan good point...wouldn't even need a ready handler then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is likely that you can't just this line of code:

```
var text__holder = $('#text__holder');
```

Until the DOM has been loaded.  If you do, you just get an empty jQuery object because it will not find any matching DOM objects.

If you know that `writeSomeTxt()` won't be called until after the DOM has been loaded, then you could do this:

```
var text__holder;

$(function() {
     text__holder = $('#text__holder');
     text__holder.text('Inside DOM ready');
    /*
      SOME MORE ACTION WITH ELEMENT
    */
});

var writeSomeTxt = function () {
    text__holder.text('Outside DOM ready');
};

// don't call this until after the DOM is loaded
// presumably based on some DOM event
writeSomeTxt();
```

---

But, really, there's no point in trying to cache a single DOM reference like that anyway so the better way to write your code would be this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#text__holder').text('Inside DOM ready');
    /*
      SOME MORE ACTION WITH ELEMENT
    */
});

var writeSomeTxt = function () {
    $('#text__holder').text('Outside DOM ready');
};

// don't call this until after the DOM is loaded
// presumably based on some DOM event
writeSomeTxt();
```

---

Or, if all this code is supposed to run at page initialization time, then just put it all inside of the `.ready()` handler.

```
$(function() {
     var text__holder = $('#text__holder');
     text__holder.text('Inside DOM ready');
    /*
      SOME MORE ACTION WITH ELEMENT
    */

    var writeSomeTxt = function () {
        text__holder.text('end of DOM ready');
    };

    writeSomeTxt();

});
```

Comment: Several months ago I've asked a question, where I put the function inside a $( document ).ready(). The answers was "why would you do that", "such a noob", etc. And my question was down-rated. Several weeks after that I posted another question where I didn't cache the DOM element. The reaction was, "why you don't cache the DOM elements"...surprisingly my question was down-rated again. Seriously what should I use.

Comment: @Gabriel - If you're doing multiple accesses to the same DOM element in the same function, then cache it locally in that function - that's just considered a good design practice to avoid calling the same selector over and over within the same function execution.  There is rarely a good reason to cache it globally though and, in fact, that can cause issues with timing or if the page is modified so within a function, just fetch it when you need it (and then retain that reference for the duration of that function).  You can also chain multiple operations in jQuery.

Comment: @Gabriel - Things should only be put in a `$(document).ready()` handler when it is code that will run at page initialization time and that code needs to access the page and you can't conveniently locate the script or call the function from a `<script>` tag at the end of the page.  That's when `$(document).ready()` is appropriate.  Putting regular function definitions inside of `$(document).ready()` that have nothing to do with page initialization and won't be called until after the page is loaded anyway is not needed.

Comment: thank you for your explanation. Now it makes sense for me. However its really frustrating, when you ask a question, because you want  to learn how to do something properly, but the reactions are hate-full. (And yes, I read the "How to ask question")  :)

Comment: @Gabriel - I haven't seen your previous questions, but there is an art to learning how to right a good question here that is both on-topic and clearly states the problem you are trying to solve.  Yes, this place is not always that friendly for people new to the site.  But, it can be very useful once you learn how to best write your questions.  The main problem with this question of yours is that it doesn't state the "real" problem you're trying to solve.  It shows sample code that has timing issues, but because we don't know the real problem, we don't know what timing solution to suggest.

Comment: @Gabriel - So, the real art to asking a good question here is to distill down your ACTUAL problem (not issues with your attempt at a solution which is what you show in this question) into a very clear and concise question, but not so dumbed down or pseudo-coded that the real issue is not shown or important detail is omitted.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare functions and variables outside `document.ready` and define the variable inside as well as call function inside once variable is defined:

```
var text__holder;//declare undefined varible

$(function() {

    text__holder = $('#text__holder');// can now define varible
    text__holder.text('Inside DOM ready');        
    // call function now that variable is defined
    writeSomeTxt();
});

var writeSomeTxt = function () {
    text__holder.text('Outside DOM ready'); 
};
```